# right way to modify d3.csv to lower case column names

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Have an app that processes csv data files provided by clients.  Javascript is case sensitive. But most stats packages are case-insensitive, so the column names come in various capitalizations.  Further the capitalizations can change if they, for instance, run the file through SAS, SPSS, or other programs and save as a new file, converting everything to upper or lower case.

So I modify D3 such that it automatically converts column names to lower case.  This can easily be done by modifying the `d3.js` source code to add `.toLocaleUpperCase()` as below:

```
    ...
    dsv.parse = function(text, f) {
      var o;
      return dsv.parseRows(text, function(row, i) {
        if (o) return o(row, i - 1);
        var a = new Function("d", "return {" + row.map(function(name, i) {
          return JSON.stringify(name.toLocaleUpperCase()) + ": d[" + i + "]";
        }).join(",") + "}");
        o = f ? function(row, i) {
          return f(a(row), i);
        } : a;
      });
    };
    ...
```

The only small challenge is that I can't just add this as a small monkey patch or plugin in my code.  This code block gets called when `d3.dsv` is imported, and that depends `d3_xhr` being defined, which requires `d3.xhr`, etc.  So I download the entire [`d3.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/d3/master/d3.js) and modify it as above, and save as `d3.mod.js`.

Can imagine this biting me or another dev in a year or two when we need to update d3.  What's the right™ way to handle a mod like this?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/protobi/729d37531c44064bf81a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `accessor` that [d3.csv](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) accepts to specify how you want the row data transformed.

The function below takes an object and converts all of its properties to lowercase. The example uses `d3.csv.parse()` instead of `d3.csv()` because its more straightforward to demo here, but you can do the same thing with `d3.csv()`.

Unfortunately, this function gets called for every row as opposed to once when it reads in the row headers. Perhaps there is a better way...

```js
var string = "Year,Make,Model,Length\n" +
  "1997,Ford,E350,2.34\n" +
  "2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38\n";

function convertPropsToLowerCase(d) {
  Object.keys(d).forEach(function(origProp) {
    var lowerCaseProp = origProp.toLocaleLowerCase();
    // if the uppercase and the original property name differ
    // save the value associated with the original prop
    // into the lowercase prop and delete the original one
    if (lowerCaseProp !== origProp) {
      d[lowerCaseProp] = d[origProp];
      delete d[origProp];
    }
  });
  return d;
}

var obj = d3.csv.parse(string, convertPropsToLowerCase);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj,null, '\t'));
/*
[
 {
  "year": "1997",
  "make": "Ford",
  "model": "E350",
  "length": "2.34"
 },
 {
  "year": "2000",
  "make": "Mercury",
  "model": "Cougar",
  "length": "2.38"
 }
] 
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is simple and clear.  My first focus was to avoid the per-row processing, but this reminds me of Knuth's principle "about 97% of the time, premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Answer (score 0):

This might be a lot faster in some circumstances. It is what I normally do to prevent iterating and changing every key one by one.

```js
let csvText = "year,make,model,length\n1997,Ford,E350,2.34\n2000,Murcury,Cougar,2.38\n"

//or - to convert your csv object into a string
// let csvText = d3.csvFormat(csvObject)

let csvRows = csvText.split("/n") //convert csv string into array of rows
let arrayOfColumnHeaders = csvRows[0].split(",") //get column names as array of strings
let newColumns = arrayOfColumnHeaders.map(column => column.toLowerCase()).join(",") //change them
csvRows[0]=newColumns //replace the headers with new ones
let newtext= csvRows.join("\n") // convert array of rows back into single string
let csvObject = d3.csvParse(newtext) //now parse it
```